# How does this where clause work?

Tags: sql, join, set, set-theory

I found [this link](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) explaining joins visually and something caught my attention.

The very last example says the following:

```
To produce the set of records unique to Table A and Table B, 
we perform the same full outer join, then exclude the records 
we don't want from both sides via a where clause.
```

[full join - venn diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAcRw.png)

The two tables for this example contain the following:

```
id name       id  name
-- ----       --  ----
1  Pirate     1   Rutabaga
2  Monkey     2   Pirate
3  Ninja      3   Darth Vader
4  Spaghetti  4   Ninja
```

Query and result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE TableA.id IS null
   OR TableB.id IS null
```

Output:

```
id    name       id    name
--    ----       --    ----
2     Monkey     null  null
4     Spaghetti  null  null
null  null       1     Rutabaga
null  null       3     Darth Vader
```

What i don't understand is, how can the where clause find null IDs on those tables ?

```
** WHERE TableA.id IS null
OR TableB.id IS null **
```

Could it be that, after the full join takes place, a bunch of nulls tuples are inserted in the final output on both tables(as expected for the full join), and then the where clause would take its null IDs from?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: It is correct for what the example wanted to show, and in fact the query does bring these results if you build those tables and execute this query.
I just need to understand how come the where clause find nulls, when there are none in the tables, at least there are none originally.

Answer (score 1):

An outer join includes all records in one or both tables, even if there are no matches.

In particular, a full outer join returns all records in each table even when the `on` clause evaluates to non-true.  The columns in the other table are not `null`.  So, your query returns the records that are in one table, but not both.

Note that this may not be the best approach for getting this information, because duplicate join keys can multiply the number of records.

Comment: Hey Gordon thanks for the reply. I understand how the query works up until the the join clause. After that, the where is selecting values that are not really present in any of those tables before the query gets executed. For example, if you run the query > select * from tableA where tableA.id is null, will not bring any results, because there are no null IDs in tableA. So, how come after the full join, the where clause is able to find nulls that are not currently present in that table. Some rule under the hood makes this possible, I just would like to understand how this really works.